# DirectX: Vertex Shader using textures

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, textures, vertex-shader

I am a beginner in Graphics Programming. I came across a case where a "ResourceView" is created out of texture and then this resource view is set as VS Resource. To summarize:

```
CreateTexture2D( D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC{ 640, 512, .... **ID3D10Texture2D_0c2c0f30** )
CreateShaderResourceView( **ID3D10Texture2D_0c2c0f30**, ..., **ID3D10ShaderResourceView_01742c80** )
VSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, [**0x01742c80**])
```

When and what are the cases when we use **textures in Vertex Shaders**?? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That completely depends on the effect you are trying to achieve.

If you want to color your vertices individually you would usually use a vertex color component. But nothing is stopping you from sampling the color from a texture. (Except that it is probably slower.)

Also, don't let the name fool you. *Textures can be used for a lot more than just coloring*. They are basically precomputed functions. For example, you could use a `Textue1D` to submit a wave function to animate clothing or swaying grass/foilage. And since it is a texture, you can use a different wave for every object you draw, without switching shaders.

The Direct3D developers just want to provide you with a maximum of flexibility. And that includes using texture resources in all shader stages.

Comment: Actually the example I am seeing, most of the cases they are using `Texture1D`. So can you give some more pointers on the wave function you are talking about.

Comment: Think of a sine wave. Instead of calculating `float sinX = sin(x)` in the shader you would simply sample the value from your sine function lookup texture: `float sinX = FunctionTexture.Sample(Sampler, x).r`. And since the function is not hardcoded in the shader you can use any data you can pack into a 1D texture (a constant, noise, gradient, etc.). `x` would be the texture coordinate in this case. The color of the pixel is the function value `f(x)`.